# Issue with operand types

Tags: c++, qt, hash, vector, operand

I get the following error:

> error: no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'QVector' and 'const float')

when trying to do:

```
dist.push_back(qPow((clusterMeanCoordinate[t].at(i) - hash_notClustered[t].at(point)), 2) + qPow((clusterMeanCoordinate[w] - hash_notClustered[w].at(point)), 2));
```

Note that:

```
QHash<int, QVector<float> > clusterMeanCoordinate;
QHash<int, QVector<float> > hash_notClustered;
QVector<float> dist;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here :

```
dist.push_back(
    qPow( (clusterMeanCoordinate[t].at(i) - hash_notClustered[t].at(point) ), 2) + 
    qPow( (clusterMeanCoordinate[w] - hash_notClustered[w].at(point)), 2));
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here you are making a substraction between a `QVector` and a `const float` :

```
   clusterMeanCoordinate[w] - hash_notClustered[w].at(point)
// QVector                  - const float
```

You can solve it by doing :

```
clusterMeanCoordinate[w].at(i) - hash_notClustered[w].at(point)
//                      ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

In the expression

```
clusterMeanCoordinate[w] - hash_notClustered[w].at(point)
```

you try to subtract a `float` from a `QVector`.